# CMD.exe: Get second column output to variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need the below command second column output `<USERNAME>` result to variables:

```
query sessions|find "Active"
>console    <USERNAME>     1   Active
```

I know the `%USERNAME%` OR `whoami` could get the current user name but this script will run using administrator account and will need to be able to capture the current active logon username. If I could select the second column of the output results and assign it to a variable.. this will be a great help.

Comment: It's going to be a little tricky if a username can contain spaces.

Comment: if only this was in Linux and it was separated by TAB: `cut -d'\t' -f2` =p

Comment: yeah, linux was easy but in windows... Jeb seems to have figure this out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case you should use `FOR /F` to capture the output

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%A in ('"query session | find "Active""') DO (
  echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E
)
```

It splits also the line at spaces and TABs, but this can be problematic if the username contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks A LOT! Jeb... this was the answer to my question:
`for /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ('"query session | find "Active""') DO (echo %%B)`

Comment: But you should test it with a username containing spaces, or you should be sure that this isn't allowed in your environment.

Comment: It was fine, we do not have spaces as username :)

Comment: You can do some testing for the position of `active`, in tokens from 1 to 10 and arrange the tokens to cater for say up to 3 spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much, from you suggest, I had done for my batch script. Windows so complicated to write script, not like Linux