# Get the n-th column of the m-th row from the multi-line output stored in a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The [CMD.exe: Get second column output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442819/) shows how to *get second column output to variable*. I have a similar question where I need to **get the n-th column of the m-th row**, having a predefined column delimiter (let's say a single TAB character) **from a multi-line output** that is already **stored in** some **variable** `!x!`.

---

As an example:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "x="
set "STDERR="
(set LF=^
%=empty line=%
)
for /F "delims=" %%E in ('
    2^>^&1 ^(^
        for /F "delims=" %%O in ^('^
            reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Artifex\GPL Ghostscript\9.26" /ve ^^^^^^^| findstr /N /R "^"^
        '^) do @^(^
            echo ^^^^^^^|%%O^
        ^)^
    ^) ^| findstr /N /R "^"
') do (
    set "LINE=%%E"
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    if "!LINE:~,1!"=="|" (
        set "x=!x!!LINE:*:=!!LF!"
    ) else (
        set "STDERR=!STDERR!!LINE!!LF!"
    )
)

echo !x!
```

which prints the following lines

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Artifex\GPL Ghostscript\9.26
>
> (Default)      REG_SZ      C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a multiline variable with embedded line feeds it's simply:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%1 in ("!x!") DO (
    echo Column1: %%1 --- Column2: %%2 --- Column3: %%3
)
```

The FOR /F loop always takes line by line (separated by line feeds).
These lines are split into tokens by the delimiters (`option: delims=`) into tokens, how many tokens are produced is controlled with the `option: tokens=`, in this case the first three tokens are mapped to `%%1`, `%%2` and `%%3`.
For more info read the help of `FOR /?`

If you want to split the tokens, the the `delims` option has to be used (the default is space and TAB).

```
For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=<a TAB CHARACTER>" ...
```

Full example:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%==%
)

set "multiline=Line1 col2!LF!Line2 colB!LF!Line3 col-two"
echo multiline - contains:!LF!!multiline!!LF!-------

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%1 in ("!multiline!") DO (
    echo Column1: %%1 --- Column2: %%2 --- Column3: %%3
)
```

Comment: Skip the first two rows with `skip=2`. Use the `delims=<TAB>`. Use `tokens=1,2,*` to get all remaining data in the third column. And read the help `FOR /?`

Comment: It looks like the output contains no TAB, but SPACE as delimiters... which brings me to a problem, because then I use the space as a delimiter, then my path (e.g. `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26`) is split as well. Since I don't know how many spaces will be in the path, this solution seems to be usless